# Proof By Contradiction logical argument

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(p \to q) \land (q \to (r \land s)) \land (\neg r \lor (\neg t \lor u)) \land (p \land t) \to u$

I am supposed to prove the valid argument above using Proof by Contradiction and so far I cant seem to find any samples on how to d it :( Please help :"(

Comment: Assume all of the hypotheses, then assume $\neg u$ and derive $\bot$.  Then you can infer $u$ from $\neg u\to\bot$.

Comment: I don't see why this is getting downvotes. People on this website are crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove something by contradiction, assume

- All the assumptions
- The negation of the conclusion

For example, in your problem, the assumptions are:

1. $p \to q$
2. $(q \to (r \land s))$
3. $(\neg r \lor (\neg t \lor u))$
4. $p$
5. $t$

The conclusion is:

1. $u$

Hence we begin the problem by assuming toward a contradiction that the following are true

1. $p \to q$
2. $(q \to (r \land s))$
3. $(\neg r \lor (\neg t \lor u))$
4. $p$
5. $t$
6. $\neg u$

Now just start arguing logically until you hit a contradiction.

For example, you could write

7. $q$ [Since $p$ is true by (4), we deduce $q$ by (1).]

Just keep building an argument like this until you finish. You may have to break into cases to deal with (3). As in:

"By (3), there are two cases. In case A, we have that $\neg r$. In case B, we have $\neg t \vee u$. Let us now consider case A..."

Your goal is to deduce a contradiction **in all cases**. Hence every case you consider has to end in the word "contradiction".

Comment: Since we are using the Proof By Contradiction, the conclusion is assumed to be ¬u.

1. p→q [P1]
2. q→(r∧s) [P2]
3. ¬r∨(¬t∨u) [P3]
4. p [Simplification from P4]
5. t [Simplification from P4]
6. q [Modus Ponen of 1 & 2]
7. (r∧s) [Modus Ponen of 2 & 6]
8. r [Simplification of 7]
9. s [Simplification of 7]
10. r→(¬t∨u) [Logical Equivalence of P3]
11. ¬t∨u [Modus Ponen of 8 & 10]
12. t→u [Logical equivalence of 11]
13. u [Modus Ponen of 5 &12]

Hence u→¬u. The conclusion u contradicts the assumption of ¬u.

^^This is my answer is this how I proof? Also im sorry bout the formattin

Answer (score 1):

A **proof by contradiction** means

- assume that the statement does not hold,
- from this assumption derive a contradiction ($\bot$),
- conclude that the assumption must have been wrong and the statement does indeed hold.

An implication $\phi \to \psi$ is true iff

> under all the assignments where the antecedent $\phi$ is true, the succedent $\psi$ is true as well

which is equivalent to stating

> there is no assignment such that the antecedent $\phi$ is true but the succedent $\psi$ is false

So if you want to **prove the truth of an implication by contradiction**,

- start with assuming the negation of the implication, that
  this, you assume that

  > there is an assignment such that the antecendent is true and the succedent is false
- from this assumption you then derive a contradiction,
- conclude that
  the assumption must have been wrong, and hence that there can indeed
  be no assignment which makes the antecedent true but the succedent
  false, hence the implication must hold.

Applied to your example, that means

- assume that the antecedent $(p \to q) \land (q \to (r \land s)) \land (\neg r \lor (\neg t \lor u)) \land (p \land t)$ is true and
- that the succedent $u$ is false, i.e. assume $\neg u$,
- derive a contradiction $\bot$,
- conclude that the assumption $\neg u$ must have been wrong, and that the succedent $u$ is indeed true if the antecendent $(p \to q) \land (q \to (r \land s)) \land (\neg r \lor (\neg t \lor u)) \land (p \land t)$ is true, hence the implication $(p \to q) \land (q \to (r \land s)) \land (\neg r \lor (\neg t \lor u)) \land (p \land t) \to u$ must hold.